# Attempting to understand Tor and it's relation to SSL

Tags: ssl, networking, encryption, tor

I'm a mathematics student trying to understand Tor. I have little knowledge of networks and how exactly they function.

Up to now I that I understand the basic functionality of Tor. A route is generated first from the consensus list, and the packet (the message) is sent through that route. The packet is encrypted multiple times using the public keys obtained from the consensus list, and each relay strips away a layer of encryption before sending it on to the next relay (side question: how does this work with bridge relays? Is the message sent to a bridge relay first and then into the public Tor network, or does it move exclusively through bridge relays?). This means that the destination IP and IP of the sender are never in the same header of the packet and this is what gives Tor its relative anonymity.

Very often however I notice that SSL is brought up when discussions regarding Tor are made. I understand that SSL encrypts the data sent between the client and the server. But if this is the case I don't see how SSL is related to Tor, since they seemingly function on a different layer.

Edit: More specifically, I'm reading about how Iranian and Chinese authorities did "Deep Package Inspection" (i'm assuming this means that they looked at the contents of each packet) to look for SSL. Is this because SSL is used by default with encrypting the different layers in an onioned packet? If so, is there a reason that looking for SSL was enough to indentify a Tor connection?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not really a programming question. Might be better suited to [security](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will find this document on the [Tor spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt) informative; specifically sections 1 & 2.

You'll find that Tor might use SSLv3 (specifically `SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`) but more often will use TLS for communicating with clients and other nodes.

Clients encrypt their data using the keys belonging to the nodes for the circuit path it chose which get unwrapped (peeled) as the data travels from relay to relay, but that data itself (and other protocol data for communicating called cells) are sent from node to node using TLS or SSL.  Some of the data that is encrypted for transport is itself encrypted (for example the contents of an HTTP request by a client to view a website over Tor).

Regarding your deep packet inspection question, they couldn't necessarily determine the traffic was Tor traffic based solely on it being SSL.  They could however use some additional information to make such assumptions such as:

- Source/destination ports: Many relays use port 443 for Tor traffic, but often 9001 is used which would be a strong indicator for Tor traffic
- Specific ciphers (common ciphers used by Tor)
- Src/dest IP address: All Tor relay IPs are known, if they have a list, they can make conclusions about Tor traffic if packets to a Tor IP are encrypted or going to/from the ORPort
- Look at SSL handshakes for identifying factors (i.e. certificates-up-front)

Seeing SSL/TLS packets alone would not be enough for them to determine traffic was Tor traffic.

Hope that helps some.